# Extreme Lag when connecting Docking Station with HDD

Tags: usb, usb-drive, external-hdd, storage, docking

### Currently Using 22.04

I just bought a [mini pc](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0CRQRP15K) using a intel i9 processor. I also jusat bout [this dual HHD docking station](https://www.bestbuy.com/site/insignia-2-bay-hdd-docking-station/6153102.p?skuId=6153102)

There is an extreme lag when I am connected to the docking station. Using my wireless mouse is almost impossible when connected. It seems to get worse if I move data around on the drive or explore the folders.

However if I connect to my G5 Dell (also running Ubuntu 22) to the docking station, its no problem. I can transfer data and do anything and not get any lag.

How can I troubleshoot this? I am not a hardware  guy. Could it be the USB port? Do I need to change a setting in Ubuntu?

**Updated Info**

I am using a freshly installed Ubuntu that was installed using a USB bootable. No problem. I was actually surprised at how fast it installed.

Hmmm, I will try to test USBs using my 2.5 Plug n Play drive. Will that be a good test?

**Final Update**

Seems like some of the USB port is of lower quality. My 2.5" hdd is fine, and the docking station works fine on different ports. I'm just ignorant of USB technology.

Comment: Since you have two PCs with Ubuntu and the external SSD/HDD enclosure works on one and does not work on the other, the problem is probably not with Ubuntu. This may be a hardware problem with your Mini PC or the enclosure. To be sure can you boot the mini PC from an Ubuntu Installation USB using the Try Ubuntu option and verify that the problem persists when you boot from USB? Edit your question and report the findings there.

Comment: Thx @user68186 - I updated the question